# Visual Studio Code Java paths in terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just started using Visual Studio Code and created a simple Hello World program in Java and it prints `Hello World` like its supposed to but I also get some paths like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:40999 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "/home/local_user/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/d9ee39ad9a8fac4ef166558e8c8af01f/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Java Programs_514b41ed/bin" Test`
with Test being the name of my .java file. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also didn't find the Settings to hide the path, but set it to output in the `DebugConsole` as a workaround,then it would not displaye the path.

add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your `launch.json` like :

```
"configurations": [
       {
         "type": "java",
         "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
         "request": "launch",
         "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
         "console": "internalConsole",
         "projectName": "my.app"
       }
     ]
```